# Use custom string value in T-SQL OPENJSON With clause

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, open-json

```
    DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(4000) = N'{ 
        "pets" : {
                "cats" : [
                { "id" : 1, "name" : "Fluffy", "sex" : "Female" },
                { "id" : 2, "name" : "Long Tail", "sex" : "Female" },
                { "id" : 3, "name" : "Scratch", "sex" : "Male" }
            ]
        }
    }'

SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.pets.cats')  WITH --we have the "main" json address here
(
id INT '$.id', --sub-address
name varchar(10) '$.name', --sub-address
sex varchar(10) '$.sex' --sub-address 
)
```

The results are:

| id | name | sex |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fluffy | Female |
| 2 | Long Tail | Female |
| 3 | Scratch | Male |

**I want to include another column which *will not depend on the JSON*, but be a custom specified string ("mammal"), so that the output is like this:**

| id | name | sex | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fluffy | Female | mammal |
| 2 | Long Tail | Female | mammal |
| 3 | Scratch | Male | mammal |

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a **constant** in your `SELECT` statement:

```
    DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(4000) = N'{ 
        "pets" : {
                "cats" : [
                { "id" : 1, "name" : "Fluffy", "sex" : "Female" },
                { "id" : 2, "name" : "Long Tail", "sex" : "Female" },
                { "id" : 3, "name" : "Scratch", "sex" : "Male" }
            ]
        }
    }'

SELECT *, 'mammal' AS Type FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.pets.cats')  WITH --we have the "main" json address here
(
id INT '$.id', --sub-address
name varchar(10) '$.name', --sub-address
sex varchar(10) '$.sex' --sub-address 
)
```